# retrieve multiple objects from one which is array of objects in mongodb

Tags: arrays, mongodb, mongodb-query

I using mongodb to save my user data along with array.
My question is how to retrieve multiple objects that matches the given value in that user array.like this:

```
{ 
    _id: { objid:'0000000000000' },
    userId: 'abc',
    userItems : [
        {
            itemName: 'mango',
            date: 24,
            month: 1,
            year: 2016
        },
        {
            itemName: 'apple',
            date: 24,
            month: 1,
            year: 2016
        },
        {
            itemName: 'orange',
            date: 22,
            month: 1,
            year: 2016
        },
        {
            itemName: 'vanilla',
            date: 23,
            month: 1,
            year: 2016
        }
    ]
}
```

and expeccted result is

```
{
    _id: { objid: '0000000000000' },
    userId: 'abc',
    userItems: [
        {
            itemName: 'mango',
            date: 24,
            month: 1,
            year: 2016
        },
        {
            itemName: 'apple',
            date: 24,
            month: 1,
            year: 2016
        }
    ]
}
```

I want all the element that matches the date,month,year from this userId userItems array please help me out from this

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Retrieve only the queried element in an object array in MongoDB collection](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3985214/retrieve-only-the-queried-element-in-an-object-array-in-mongodb-collection)

Comment: @Muhammad Sami : Did you checked my answer?

Comment: Thanks this helped me alot i am testing it Thanks bro

Answer (score 1):

We can find result by aggregation framework.

```
db.user.aggregate(
   {
     $unwind : "$userItems" 
   },
   {
      $match: {
        "userItems.date" : 24, 
        "userItems.month" : 1, 
        "userItems.year" : 2016
      }
   },
   {
      $group: {
         "_id" : { "id":"$_id","userId":"$userId"},
         "userItems" : {$push:"$userItems"}
      }
   },
   {
       $project:{
          "_id": "$_id.id", 
          "userId": "$_id.userId",
          "userItems": 1 
       }
   }
)
```

Comment: I have seen that format before, but I have never used it, so I can't comment on whether or not the best way. Upvoting anyway, because I know it's one of the ways to do it.

Comment: This is the best thing in mongo, you must learn. Aggregation framework is good for Grouping and projecting required data. Best when collection size is getting bigger and bigger.

Comment: Thanks, I will check it out.

Comment: Thank you all this answer solved my problem but for my issue i dont need $projection. Thanks Thankyou all

Comment: Welcome. I have given $projection to give knowledge about how you can project result coming from group. This project will give object similar to your input. You can use projection or not, that's your need. If someone pointing to you to right direction or answer, you should accept answer. You must not have visited the link I have given in last comment. People see your acceptance ratio.

Answer (score 0):

```
db.collectioName.find(
   {
      nameOfArrayYouarelookingIn: {
         $elemMatch: {
            ArrayFieldOneName: 1,
            ArrayFieldTwoName: 'blahblah'
         }
      }
   }
)
```

See [$elemMatch documentation](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/elemMatch/) for more details and examples.

Comment: I have used it but it only gives me the first matching object not more than that

Comment: this will match whole document. and not give matching objects inside of array property. @VSO check my answer